# Crash when calling Obj-C method with nullability annotations from Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift2

We came across this issue after we upgraded to `AFNetworking` `2.6.0`, which added nullability annotations, and `UIWebView`'s extension `-loadRequest:progress:success:failure:` started crashing. Below is minimal example causing the crash.

Obj-C class:

```
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
@interface Foo : NSObject

- (void) fooWithSuccess:(NSString* (^)(NSString* string))success;

@end
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END

@implementation Foo

- (void)fooWithSuccess:(NSString* (^)(NSString*))success
{
    // EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the following line
    NSLog(@"%@", success(@"Foo"));
}

@end
```

Calling the code above from swift (e.g. in `viewDidAppear()`):

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
    foo.fooWithSuccess { string in
        return string
    }
}
```

However, it works without problems if Obj-c code is either not annotated or return parameter of `success` block is nullable:

```
- (void) fooWithSuccess:(NSString* __nullable (^)(NSString* string))success;
```

It seems to us that this behaviour is bug in Obj-c and Swift2 interoperability, and we are wondering if anyone has any insight / we are missing something.

---

### Update

Issue is only with Swift2. When running in Swift 1.2 program behaves as expected.

### Radar

Radar has been filed: rdar://22911182